# How to disable AngularJS Kendo UI Editor

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have tried using `k-content-editable` and well as just the generic `data-ng-disabled` but neither of these worked. Looking at the documentation it's not even clear to me there is a way to disable the control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom directive:

```
   .directive("kNgDisabled", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(e, widget) {
            var value = scope.$eval(attr.kNgDisabled);

            $(widget.body).attr("contenteditable", !value);

            scope.$watch(attr.kNgDisabled, function(value) {
              $(widget.body).attr("contenteditable", !value);
            });
          })
        }
      }
    });
```

Then use it like this:

```
<textarea kendo-editor k-ng-disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Here is a live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/AdApu

Comment: Thank you! It's a shame there is no way to do this via the editor itself.

Answer (score 2):

Add following code in your Angular controller->

```
 var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
    x.addEventListener("focus", myFocusFunction, true);

    function myFocusFunction() {
         $($('#keFinding').data().kendoEditor.body).attr('contenteditable', false);  
    }
```